# javascript test method not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I have a conditional logic based on the `OS` version no. in the browser `useragent` string.

Here is the code i tried.

```
var useragent = "Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-gb; HTC_DesireZ_A7272 Build/FRG83D";

if((/2.3/).test(useragent)){
   alert("2");
}
else if((/3./).test(useragent)){
   alert("3");
}
else if((/4./).test(useragent)){
   alert("4");
}
else {
   alert("5");
}
```

I always get an alert with `3`.

I tried replacing `test` method with `indexOf` and i get an alert with `5`.

Can somebody explain why `(/3./).test(useragent)` returns true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always get this because your regex `/3./` means - match 3 and any symbol behind it. You have to escape the `.`.

For example try `/3\./`, and respectively for the others: `/2\.3/`, `/4\./`.

Your code should look something like that:

```
var useragent = "Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-gb; HTC_DesireZ_A7272 Build/FRG83D";

if ((/Android 2\./).test(useragent)){
   alert("2");
} else if((/Android 3\./).test(useragent)){
   alert("3");
} else if((/Android 4\./).test(useragent)){
   alert("4");
} else {
   alert("5");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Minko, It worked. I should have gone through the javascript regex guide which tells `.` as special character.